# Как сгенерировать n строк в DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Задача состоит в следующем:
Создать файл csv с n строк, в каждой из строк должен быть рандомный uuid и один из трех известных типов

```
import pandas as pd
import uuid
import random as rd

random_uuid = uuid.uuid4()
list_of_types = ['PROFILE_ID', 'CLIENT_ID', 'MDM_ID']
randomType = rd.choice(list_of_types)
columns = ['ACTION']
data = [
    'ADD'
]
df = pd.DataFrame([data], columns=columns)
df.insert(0, 'ID', random_uuid)
df.insert(1, 'ID_TYPE', randomType)
df.to_csv(r'Документы\test_file7.csv', sep=';', index= False)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в примере генерируется файл с одной строкой, не могу понять как сделать так, чтобы создавалось нужное количество уникальных строк.

Решение через numpy repeat не подходит, т.к. просто повторяется первая строка

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat([data], 5), columns=columns)
df.insert(0, 'ID', random_uuid)
df.insert(1, 'ID_TYPE', randomType)
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\vsugo\OneDrive\Документы\test_file10.csv', sep=';', index= False)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду признателен подсказкам.

Answer (score 1):

Генерируйте списки для каждого столбца и создавайте датафрейм сразу из них. `insert` - очень неэффективная операция.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [uuid.uuid4() for _ in range(n)],
    'ID_TYPE': rd.choices(list_of_types, k=n)
})
```

Обратите внимание, что я использую функцию `random.choices`, а не `random.choice`, она доступна начиная с версии питона `3.6`.

Comment: Благодарю! Короткое и корректное решение =)

Comment: Более эффективно с точки зрения расхода памяти заменить списковое включение на генераторное выражение